# What to do when a co-author submitted corrected proofs without the first author's knowledge?

Tags: phd, paper-submission, authorship, collaboration, proofreading

I finished my PhD studies about a year ago, and am no longer working at the university. My supervisor, and co-author of three papers, urged me to work with him on the fourth paper in order to get it published. In fact, his contribution to the paper was very small. He should act as corresponding author and deal with the submission, which -- I thought -- would be a relieve. However, this did not work out. First, he made changes to the revised version of our manuscript before submitting it, which resulted in a revised paper among other things missing a figure.

The paper was accepted anyway, and we received the uncorrected proofs. I cannot say exactly why, but although I told him I am working on it (which he said did not notice), my co-author just submitted the corrected proofs without my knowledge. Now, among other errors, a whole paragraph is missing, and I fear this version of the paper is published online very soon.

I am really disappointed and angry. I make a lot of mistakes myself, and I do not expect my co-author to agree in everything I write, but does team work not imply that you inform your team before submitting the final work?

Of course, I tried to submit a revised version of the corrected proofs and convince the journal to use these, but I assume this is pointless. Once the proofs are uploaded there is usually nothing that can be done.

Maybe, there is no real question here, besides: What can I do now?

Comment: Which field/journal is this? I cannot add or remove a paragraph when submitting the corrected proofs, such changes would require approval by the editor or even reviewers. Can you?

Comment: It is an mdpi journal and the paper was submitted as a word document. I don't know how he managed to delete the paragraph, but it has disappeared. The editor made a comment on this paragraph so that it appeared underlined. I supect someone just hit delete.

Answer (score 4):

> Of course, I tried to submit a revised version of the corrected proofs and convince the journal to use these, but I assume this is pointless.

It isn't! This happens very frequently. But do talk to some human contact person (at least via email) to make sure this is accepted.

> Team work

It seems like there hasn't been much team work. Talk to your former advisor, directly, on the phone; tell him you want to coordinate the proof work with him, and mention that in the currently submitted versions there are problems X, Y and Z. This should piss him off.

Don't leave this to email - either face-to-face or voice call, for a stronger impression and sense of urgency.